# No such file or directory: Cannot execute but is visible to ls, file and tab-completion

Tags: bash, ubuntu, amazon-lightsail

I'm installing flexnet on an amazon lightsail instance. I've just extracted the contents to `/opt` and in trying to run any lm* command. With `ls` I can see I have ownership and permission to execute. I can run `file` on any of the contents of the folder and it will tell me what it is.

But when I try to execute anything, bash will complain with No such file or directory. Example:

```sh
jabozzo@ICUC_services:/opt/flexnet/bin$ ls -all
total 4684
drwxr-xr-x 2 jabozzo jabozzo    4096 Nov  8  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 jabozzo jabozzo    4096 Dec 19 15:46 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jabozzo jabozzo       6 Dec 14  2016 lmcksum -> lmutil
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jabozzo jabozzo       6 Dec 14  2016 lmdown -> lmutil
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jabozzo jabozzo 1551536 Nov  8  2016 lmgrd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jabozzo jabozzo       6 Dec 14  2016 lmhostid -> lmutil
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jabozzo jabozzo       6 Dec 14  2016 lmnewlog -> lmutil
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jabozzo jabozzo       6 Dec 14  2016 lmpath -> lmutil
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jabozzo jabozzo       6 Dec 14  2016 lmremove -> lmutil
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jabozzo jabozzo       6 Dec 14  2016 lmreread -> lmutil
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jabozzo jabozzo       6 Dec 14  2016 lmstat -> lmutil
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jabozzo jabozzo       6 Dec 14  2016 lmswitchr -> lmutil
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jabozzo jabozzo 1362736 Nov  8  2016 lmutil
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jabozzo jabozzo       6 Dec 14  2016 lmver -> lmutil
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jabozzo jabozzo 1701200 Nov  8  2016 mgcld
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jabozzo jabozzo   49088 Nov  8  2016 mgls_admin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jabozzo jabozzo    1593 Nov  8  2016 mgls_child_ver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jabozzo jabozzo  112736 Nov  8  2016 mgls_ok
jabozzo@ICUC_services:/opt/flexnet/bin$ file lmutil 
lmutil: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
jabozzo@ICUC_services:/opt/flexnet/bin$ ./lmutil
-bash: ./lmutil: No such file or directory
jabozzo@ICUC_services:/opt/flexnet/bin$ /opt/flexnet/bin/lmutil 
-bash: /opt/flexnet/bin/lmutil: No such file or directory
```

In the example, if I type `./lmu` and tab complete, it is completed as `./lmutils`. Using absolute path doesn't help either. I've also checked for the presence of needed shared libraries:

```sh
jabozzo@ICUC_services:/opt/flexnet/bin$ ldd lmutil 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe09bb1000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7e75ab4000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7e757ab000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7e75595000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7e751cb000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7e74fc7000)
    /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7e75cd1000)
```

Comment: Is your Lightsail instance 64-bit?

Comment: Yes, it's 64 bit. `uname -a` -> `Linux ICUC_services 4.4.0-1044-aws #53-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 11 13:49:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to run an executable and you get the "no such file or directory" error, this often means that the executable is unable to find the correct dynamic loader.  If you look at the output from the `file` command, you see:

```
...interpreter /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3...
```

Does your system have `/lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3`? If not, that suggests that these binaries were built for a different architecture (e.g., 64 bit vs 32 bit) or for a different version of the C library (`glibc`).

Solutions include:

- Install packages that contain the necessary interpreter.
- Find a set of executables that have been compiled for the version of the C library installed on your system.
- Run things inside a Docker container or `chroot` environment that has the appropriate C library installed.

A hacky solution would be to use the [patchelf](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html) command to change the interpreter path embedded in the binaries.  Depending on your environment, that might work or it just may make everything crash.

Also, just symlinking from the `.so.2` to `.so.3` might work.

Comment: Also possibly of interest: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Lmutil-error-lib64ld-lsb-x86-64-so-3-bad-ELF-interpreter.html

Comment: I was missing the package `lsb-core`. Now it works. Thank you!